# Attribute mapping SAML token Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an Enterprise Application configurated at Azure Active Directory. In the SAML token we supply the external application with information about the user that is logged in.

The list of properties is quite extensive but in this list we miss the property "user.mobile". Is this correct and how can we add this correctly[ in the SAML token.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03cEe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot include user's mobile number in a claim. Neither through  [customizing SAML token for enterprise applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization), nor via [claims mapping policies (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-claims-mapping).

So, the only last resort is using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user). If your application needs the user mobile phone it can either ask the user or query the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user).

Comment: Is this possible now? to include user's mobile number in a claim